# How to use audioDeviceIOCallback, audioDeviceAboutToStart and audioDeviceStopped in a simple audio recorder program

Tags: c++, audio, audio-recording, juce

Using Juce, I tried to create a simple audio recorder from the [demo runner](https://github.com/WeAreROLI/JUCE/tree/master/examples/DemoRunner).
I've extracted the [AudioRecordingDemo](https://github.com/WeAreROLI/JUCE/blob/master/examples/Audio/AudioRecordingDemo.h) to create audio recorder based on a simple audio project.

When I'm clicking on the start recording button, the sampleRate still have the default value:

```
void startRecording(const File& file)
    {
        stop();

        if (sampleRate > 0)
        { 
            // Create an OutputStream to write to our destination file...
```

> sampleRate = 0.0

In the AudioRecordingDemo, the audioDeviceAboutToStart increment the sample rate. But I don't have any AudioIODevice in my main component.

```
void audioDeviceAboutToStart(AudioIODevice* device) override
{
    sampleRate = device->getCurrentSampleRate();

}
```

The AudioIODeviceCallback that sets up the input and ouput is also never called in my code. I tried to use it in my MainComponent class without success.

I also tried to make the MainComponent class inherits from the AudioIODeviceCallback :

```
class MainComponent : public Component,
         private AudioIODeviceCallback,
         private MidiInputCallback

{
public:
//...
```

I found this method in the [Build a multi-polyphonic synthesiser tutorial](https://docs.juce.com/master/tutorial_mpe_introduction.html).

But when I tried this, I got an overwriting error in the main class.

So here is my problem, how to use the AudioIODeviceCallback, audioDeviceAboutToStart and audioDeviceStopped that are defined in the AudioRecordingDemo class in my project ?

You can find the source code [here](https://gitlab.com/DamienAuvray/simpleaudiorecorder/).

Comment: https://forum.juce.com/t/how-to-use-audiodeviceiocallback-audiodeviceabouttostart-and-audiodevicestopped-in-a-simple-audio-recorder-program/30701

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed my problem by adding the audioDeviceIOCallback to my MainComponent Class :

```cpp
void audioDeviceIOCallback (const float** /*inputChannelData*/, int /*numInputChannels*/,
                            float** outputChannelData, int numOutputChannels,
                            int numSamples) override
{
    // make buffer
    AudioBuffer<float> buffer (outputChannelData, numOutputChannels, numSamples);

    // clear it to silence
    buffer.clear();
}
```

The source code up to date : [SimpleAudioRecorder](https://gitlab.com/DamienAuvray/simpleaudiorecorder/)